# Where to validate the request object and do exception handling?

Tags: validation, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0, exception

I have a scenario where I am using Manager-Repository design pattern. Flow is like; request comes from browser to ApiController to Manager to Repository.

I am not sure if I should validate the request object and do exception handling in ApiController or Manager or Repository. Appreciate any suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Exception handling should be at all levels. You start with client-side, then ApiController, then Manager and lastly Repository. Why on all levels?

Client-side provides better UI experience and handles most of the user errors.

ApiController needs to validate request object and handle any exceptions.

Manager needs to validate business logic and handle exceptions (I presume that Manager can and will be used not only by ApiController).

Same goes for Repository, it needs to handle any data-level exceptions. (I presume that Repository can and will be used by multiple Manager-like classes).

Every layer of the application needs to handle exceptions and relay that information upstream, or not depending on severity.

But this is only my opinion, you should do whatever fits your needs.